# Laravel eloquent relation query multiple

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have a model with a relation table and a pivot table.

**Books**

*id name*

1  book 1

2  book 2

3  book 3

**Types**

*id name*

1  fiction

2  nonfiction

3  magazine

4  hardback

5  journal

6  comedy

**BookwithType**

*book_id type_id*

1       2

1       3

2       2

2       4

as you can see a book can have more than one type, now what i want to do is a query to search for all of the types a book may have based on user input. for example if a user searches for a non fiction magazine book i would want book 1 to be returned.

at the moment my code is returning both book 1 and 2 - because book 2 is a non fiction book however it should not return unless BOTH conditions are met.

current code

```
$search = ['nonfiction','magazine'];

$books = Book::whereHas('types', $filter = function($query) use ($search){$query->whereIn('name',$search);
})
->get();
```

model

```
    public function types()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Type');
    }
```

i can achieve my results with this function in the model however i am not able to pass a variable in this way, how can I do it?

```
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Book')->wherePivotIn('type_id', [1,2]);
```

Answer (score 0):

**in your book model make hasMany relation with booktype table by bookid**

```
use App\Book;//in top of your model
     public function bookWithType() {
            return $this->hasMany(Book::class, 'book_id');
        }
```